# How to find which column value is differ after using except command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables. Using "except" command I can find the mismatch values between two tables.

EX:

```
(select * from test_table3) except (select * from test_table1)
```

Now I need to find the difference in which column's value? How can i find that column?
I am using SQL 2005.

Comment: Use Case to find out the diffrence

Comment: How?can you please give an example?

Comment: I think that in this case a `FULL JOIN` can be a better fit

Comment: I think you have a unique key field in these two tables.

Comment: sorry bro. i have to match all the fields so i can't use any JOINING also i dont have any PK.I can go only using the except command.Now i need to find the return row is differ in which column's value

Comment: @riad - That you have to match all the fields doesn't mean that you can't use any `JOIN`s, just that the join condition is done on all the fields

Comment: Any other way except JOINING?

Comment: You don't have a PK? No unique constraint either? How do you expect any query to identify a row? If you update all the columns, how could you ever match it to what the row *used* to look like? You need to get your design right before you start solving business problems (or writing oddball queries).

Comment: Post the table structures please...

Comment: How big are the tables?  How many columns?  I have an idea, but it might not work on a large volume of data.